# Formatting issue when using "Fixed" for decimal rounding

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a report with total, max, min, avg, at the bottom of it. For some of the values they need to have a certain number of decimal places, and in some places they are supposed to have no decimal places. Whenever I set the number to "Fixed" and decimal places to "0" it seems to add space to the right of the number within the textbox. All of my fields are right-aligned so this moves them over to the left, in some cases pushing the numbers past the limits of the field.

Is there an easy way to fix this at all? Is this a known bug?

Answer (score 2):

It can be due negative number format. Do you have negative number format configured to be shown after the number ( in control panel)?

[image]

For positive numbers, Windows displays a blank space.

Also, you can try to set the `Format` property to #.##0